append is editing arrays in arrays
I am making a program to log array coordinates that have not been placed in an array.
Strangely, using append to add an array into another array doesn't work, and just edited the second value.
string = "v>v<vvv<<vv^v<v>v"
location = [0, 0]
been_to = [[0, 0]]
string = list(string)

def notInArray(array, element):
    print(array)
    for i in array:
        if i == element:
            return False
    return True

for i in string:
    if i == "v":
        #down
        location[1] = location[1] - 1
    elif i == "^":
        #up
        location[1] = location[1] + 1
    elif i == ">":
        #right
        location[0] = location[0] + 1
    elif i == "<":
        #left
        location[0] = location[0] - 1
    if notInArray(been_to, location):
        been_to.append(location)

And output:
[[0, 0]]
[[0, 0], [1, -1]]
[[0, 0], [1, -2]]
[[0, 0], [0, -2]]
[[0, 0], [0, -3]]
[[0, 0], [0, -4]]
[[0, 0], [0, -5]]
[[0, 0], [-1, -5]]
[[0, 0], [-2, -5]]
[[0, 0], [-2, -6]]
[[0, 0], [-2, -7]]
[[0, 0], [-2, -6]]
[[0, 0], [-2, -7]]
[[0, 0], [-3, -7]]
[[0, 0], [-3, -8]]
[[0, 0], [-2, -8]]
[[0, 0], [-2, -9]]

As you can see, append edits the second array in the array.

You append the same location list multiple times to been_to.

thanks mkrieger1 for helping edit my question

what do you mean? i can only find one append statement in my program

It gets repeated in a loop.

yeah... but doesn't it change location every time?

It doesn't make a copy. Change that to been_to.append(location.copy())

it works better, although it puts None in for some reason.

sorry output is too long.

BTW, you don't need to write your own notInArray() function. Python has a built-in not in operator: if location not in been_to:

Edit the question to show the new output.

There's no need to convert string to a list. You can iterate over the characters in a string with a for loop.
